# Intern Dojo Multiple Errors on Runner startup

Tags: typescript, dojo, intern, istanbul

I'm trying to create functional tests for an ongoing project built with Dojo and TypeScript. When I try to start the intern-runner to start my functional tests I get the following error:

```
        ReferenceError: __cov_3BgxwjlWVK8G4w9ax1XO$A is not defined
      at Object.<anonymous>  <C:\workspaces\QLiveFrontend\P89_Web\node_modules\intern\node_modules\escodegen\node_modules\source-map\lib\source-map\source-node.js:5:0>
      at Module._compile  <module.js:570:32>
      at Object.Module._extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js]  <node_modules\intern\node_modules\istanbul\lib\hook.js:107:24>
      at Module.load  <module.js:487:32>
```

and also this one a couple of times:

```
TypeError: SourceNode is not a constructor
    at toSourceNodeWhenNeeded (C:\workspaces\QLiveFrontend\P89_Web\node_modules\intern\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:535:20)
    at generateIdentifier (C:\workspaces\QLiveFrontend\P89_Web\node_modules\intern\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:866:16)
    at CodeGenerator.Identifier (C:\workspaces\QLiveFrontend\P89_Web\node_modules\intern\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:2244:20)
    at CodeGenerator.generateExpression (C:\workspaces\QLiveFrontend\P89_Web\node_modules\intern\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:2427:28)
    at CodeGenerator.MemberExpression (C:\workspaces\QLiveFrontend\P89_Web\node_modules\intern\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:1910:28)
    at CodeGenerator.generateExpression (C:\workspaces\QLiveFrontend\P89_Web\node_modules\intern\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:2427:28)
    at CodeGenerator.MemberExpression (C:\workspaces\QLiveFrontend\P89_Web\node_modules\intern\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:1910:28)
    at CodeGenerator.generateExpression (C:\workspaces\QLiveFrontend\P89_Web\node_modules\intern\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:2427:28)
    at CodeGenerator.UpdateExpression (C:\workspaces\QLiveFrontend\P89_Web\node_modules\intern\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:2009:26)
    at CodeGenerator.generateExpression (C:\workspaces\QLiveFrontend\P89_Web\node_modules\intern\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:2427:28)
```

where do I have to look to find the error? Istanbul,Intern,Escodegen or something entirely different?

Answer (score 0):

These errors are due to code coverage instrumentation being inserted somewhere it shouldn't be. As a quick fix, you can disable code coverage entirely by setting `excludeInstrumentation` to `true` in your Intern config. The better fix is to set `excludeInstrumentation` to a regular expression that excludes your tests, node_modules, browser_modules, etc., but lets your actual code be instrumented.